# SQL sub query return value subtractions

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing a sort based on names, for that, I am using `rownum`, since the sorting is according to names I am trying to fetch next and prev id according to `rownum` column.

I am trying to subtract subquery result near WHERE clause but its not showing any result. If I place a numeric value directly i.e 3 it will subtract properly.

I have tried typecasting the return value but it still gives me empty result set.

```
SELECT inner_id, first_name, rank as sort_id
FROM 
(
SELECT id as inner_id, first_name, (@rownum:=@rownum+1) rank 
    FROM ympa_applications, (SELECT @rownum:=0) t
    ORDER BY first_name ASC
) t WHERE rank = ( (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(rank AS UNSIGNED) FROM ympa_applications WHERE inner_id=132) - 1 )
```

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results.

Comment: Expected result would be the prev row of the current selected row. But if i remove the subtraction condition then the result set is following

Inner query result
https://imgur.com/a/YWMiS4a

Final result after removing the subtraction condition
https://imgur.com/a/mWg3zYx

Comment: This is a reference code i used : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fee74/6